# Data source connection string in SSRS with AG listener

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have three nodes(instances) with NAME-DB01, NAME-DB02, NAME-03.
On each node i have Availability group with a listener.
For example on instance NAME-02 i have 2 databases B1,B2 and AG01 and AG02.
On that instance B1 is set under AG01L01 (LO1 is listener) and primary and B2 under AG02LO1 as secondary. On instance NAME-DB03 B1 under AG01L01 is secondary and B2 under AG02LO1  is primary.
What i want to do is to write a data source connection string for my Reporting services that will always the same for AG01LO1 or AG02LO1 for B1 and B2.

I want to have connection string set to AG not to database name directly.

My current example is:

```
Data Source=ICTESTAG01L01; Initial Catalog=B1
```

but because it's not primary i get error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/reporting-services-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes i already so that article and i did like is said there: Data Source=[AvailabilityGroupListenerName];Initial Catalog = AdventureWorks2016; ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly, but error is the same as i wrote above

Comment: Did you post this on dba.stackexchange.com as well? they might be able to help you there as well.